# Drag div to other div

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Here is the code and DEMO of my project: http://jsbin.com/erofot/1

What I want to do?

I want to users can move .draggabledivs only into table (table/.dropable div)
I want to users can move divs beetween table(days) horizontaly.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).resizable();
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone"});
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: so just table accept .draggable divs

Comment: You want to snap to the table rows: `$(".draggable").draggable({snap: "#dropable"});`

Comment: table must accept .draggable on move bt other element, anywhere else on page dont

Comment: not work well, please show me on jsbin

Comment: Please check my answer, which includes an updated JSBin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the 'revert' option on the draggable elements, in tandem with the 'accept' option on the droppable method:

```
$(function() {
$( ".draggable" ).resizable();
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert: 'invalid', snap: "#dropable"});
$( "#drop_here td" ).droppable({
  accept: '.draggable.accept_me',
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
  });
});
```

I've updated your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erofot/6/edit).

To help illustrate the functionality, i've added an additional `accept_me` classname to the **first 3 draggable elements**. If you drag either of them onto a table row, it'll accept it and snap into position. If you try to drag & drop any icon other than one of the top three, it'll revert back to it's original position.

Let me know if you need further clarification on this.

Comment: yes but only first 3 divs can drag , 4,5,6 with icnos I can drag , becuse they wont

Comment: As stated in my answer, I added the `.accept_me` to the first 3 icons to show you the difference in functionality. Check this updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erofot/6/edit) to see them all working.

Comment: yes I see that, thanks... but can snap be a padding-top:10px; and padding-bottom:10px, becouse I need to put divs into middle of row. Also why helper:'clone' dont work and refresh the page every 5 seconds?

Comment: See this answer for a solution for vertical centering upon dropping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388679/how-do-i-force-jquery-to-center-an-element-when-it-is-dragged-to-and-snapped-to. Also, if you use the "clone" helper option, it only reveals a clone whilst dragging, but your icon will disappear once dropped.