# Centering draggable elements inside droppable using jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Below is an example of what I have been able to achieve so far...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    scroll: false,
    stack: false,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      $(".droparea").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
  $(".droparea").droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var drop_el = $(this).offset();
      var drag_el = ui.draggable.offset();
      var left_end = (drop_el.left + ($(this).width() / 2)) - (drag_el.left + (ui.draggable.width() / 2));
      var top_end = (drop_el.top + ($(this).height() / 2)) - (drag_el.top + (ui.draggable.height() / 2));
      $(this).addClass("highlight").find("p");
      ui.draggable.animate({
        top: '+=' + top_end,
        left: '+=' + left_end
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 50%;
  top: -50px
}
.droparea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="droparea">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="droparea">

</div>
```

Sometimes it refuses to center the .item div... The `.item` div has to be dragged into the inner part of the `.droparea` element, otherwise it won't center the `.item` element after releasing the item element.
Just wondering if there is any more elegant way to make a draggable div centered into the closest droppable element.

Comment: I have just noticed that sometimes it refuses to center the **.item** div... The **.item** div has to be dragged into the inner part of the **.droparea** element...otherwise it won't center the **.item** element after releasing the item element.

Comment: There's a trail after the red square when droppping it (in chrome), you can fix this with `outline: 1px solid transparent` :)

Comment: For me it is working fine... are you talking about the revert when more than `50%` of the draggable is outside droppable..?

Comment: as I have already mentioned , sometimes I need to drag the draggable div into the center of droppable div , othwerwise it won't snap to the center of the droppable element. Now when I changed the tolerance to "touch". It's kinda working as I wanted to but it's now occasionally centering the draggable element between two droppable elements.

Comment: I have just found a working example of what I wanted to achieve.. http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/JTKBR/

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery UI's inbuilt [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) utility method for centering the dropped item as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    revert: 'invalid',
    stack: false,
    cursor: "pointer",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      $(".droparea").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
  $(".droparea").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
      $this.addClass("highlight");
      ui.draggable.position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $this,
        using: function(pos) {
          $(this).animate(pos, "slow", "linear");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.droparea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: 1px solid transparent
}
.highlight {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="droparea">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>


<div class="droparea"></div>
<div class="droparea"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this topic, apologies for a duplicate question.

[How do I force jquery to center an element when it is dragged to and snapped to another container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388679/how-do-i-force-jquery-to-center-an-element-when-it-is-dragged-to-and-snapped-to)

So in this case the solution would look like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".item" ).draggable({
  scroll: false,
  revert: 'invalid',
  stack: false,
  create: function(){$(this).data('position',$(this).position())},
  cursor: "pointer",
  start:function(){$(this).stop(true,true)},
  drag: function(event, ui)
  {
   $( ".droparea" ).removeClass( "highlight" );
  }
 });
 $( ".droparea" ).droppable({
  accept: ".item",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
   $( this ).addClass( "highlight" ).find( "p" );
   snapToMiddle(ui.draggable,$(this));
  }
 });
});

function snapToMiddle(dragger, target){
    var topMove = target.position().top - dragger.data('position').top + (target.outerHeight(true) - dragger.outerHeight(true)) / 2;
    var leftMove= target.position().left - dragger.data('position').left + (target.outerWidth(true) - dragger.outerWidth(true)) / 2;
    dragger.animate({top:topMove,left:leftMove},{duration:200,easing:'linear'});
}
```

```css
.item { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;}
.droparea { width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; margin: 2px; border: 1px solid #000; outline: 1px solid transparent}
.highlight {border: 1px solid blue}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div  class="droparea">
 <div class="item"> </div> 
</div>


<div class="droparea"> </div>
<div class="droparea"> </div>
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily a duplicate question because the question you're referring to isn't using droppables, with which we can do better things ;)