# How to detect center line of a canvas to center a object when it dragged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

This question belongs to fabricJS and canvas.When I dragged a object to a canvas I need to detect center line and snap to it. I found some similar approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388679/how-do-i-force-jquery-to-center-an-element-when-it-is-dragged-to-and-snapped-to). But it deals with `div` elements. I need to deal with center line of the canvas. How I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define snap functionality manually with `moving` option. Try following.

```
    'object:moving' : function(e){
    var objCenter = e.target.getLeft() + (e.target.getWidth()/2);


    var targetLine = canvas.left+(canvas.width/2); 


    if(objCenter > targetLine-10 && objCenter < targetLine+10){

        e.target.left = targetLine - (e.target.getWidth()/2) ;
    }else{
        e.target.setOpacity(1);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 3):

**CenterPoint of a Canvas or Fabric.Rect**

If you have a rectangle defined like this:

```
var rect = {x:0, y:0, width:50, height:30};
```

You can calculate the centerpoint of the rectangle like this:

```
var centerX = x+width/2;
var centerY = y+height/2;
```

**Midpoint between 2 points (== midpoint of a line segment)**

If you have a line segment defined like this:

```
var line={ x0:0, y0:50, x1:100, y1:50 }
```

You can calculate the midpoint of the line segment like this:

```
var dx = x1-x0;
var dy = y1-y0
var midX = x0 + dx*0.50;
var midY = y0 + dy*0.50;
```